# Cannot associate a new account and login to an old one

Tags: support, login, association

I cannot create a new associated account: when I create an account on puzzles (using my stackexchange credentials), a new separate account is created.

Moreover, when I try to login to my existing mathoverflow account, a *new* account is created.

I have no puzzle.SE or mathoverflow cookies.